# Не отображается картинка в Splash Screen

Tags: android

Не могу понять в чем причина. Сделала экран загрузки, но не отображаются View компоненты, которые на ней расставила. В консоли нет никаких ошибок

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_phone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

SplashScreenActivity

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
    // Время в милесекундах, в течение которого будет отображаться Splash Screen
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // По истечении времени, запускаем главный активити, а Splash Screen закрываем
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Стектрейс

```
04-24 07:02:20.225 5986-5986/ru.test.kidsphone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.test.kidsphone, PID: 5986
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.test.kidsphone/ru.test.kidsphone.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at ru.test.kidsphone.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59780/discussion-on-question-by------splash-screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя `app:srcCompat`, Вам необходимо наследовать `AppCompatActivity`, вместо `Activity`, т.к. реализация `Activity`, не знает о методах библиотеки поддержки.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо.